Can my employer require me to wear a dirty uniform and refuse to provide additional shirts?
I've been working at my current job for six months. Initially, I was told I could wear whatever I wanted as long as I had closed-toe shoes. Recently, my employer provided me with one work shirt, a green t-shirt with the company logo, and said I must wear it every day.
For the past three days, I've worn this shirt, which has accumulated pizza sauce, pepper juice, flour, dough, BBQ sauce, Alfredo sauce, sardine juice, butter, and sweat. It's become unsanitary and disgusting, and I feel sick wearing it. I explained this to my manager, but he insists I must wear this shirt to clock in, even though it's filthy and I haven't had a chance to wash it due to my late work hours and the laundromat's schedule.
My employer says I have to buy additional shirts from a specific website, but I can't afford to do so right now. Meanwhile, other employees are allowed to wear a variety of clothing, including cut-off t-shirts, basketball shorts, Crocs, and house slippers.
What are my rights in this situation? Can my employer legally require me to wear a dirty uniform and refuse to provide additional shirts? How should I handle this with my employer or HR?

Does your contract say anything about uniforms?

Your rights are obviously dependent on the country you work in. In Europe you will find written contracts and paragraphs upon paragraphs of labor laws for employee protection, while in other countries (US and third world) you are on your own, with nothing written down, no protections, and the threat of instant unemployment over your head. I am sure you will get better answers, if you tell us where in the world you are (maybe even federal state if the US) and whether or not you have your own employment contract that says something about the situation.

And just to make sure "the obvious" is actually true, the shirt you are wearing is employer branding, not a government mandated safety regulation, right?

@New2wheels-Pray4Me: "Meanwhile, other employees are allowed to wear a variety of clothing, including cut-off t-shirts, basketball shorts, Crocs, and house slippers." We do not know your job, and we do not know their job. The difference might be very important (I mean, if the jobs are different).

Providing location is key to having an accurate answer.  Also please mention the establishment name so I be sure to never go there.  Its gross having an employee wear a three day old shirt.

Some information on why the other employees can wear what they like but you can't (if there is a reason) would be relevant. If it is arbitrary and singling you out it might constitute workplace bullying

More information is really needed to address this properly. In a comment below you mention Marion, Indiana; so it seems you are in the USA. Judging by what you say your shirt is dirty with it seems you work in pizzeria (or at least some type of restaurant); is this a chain establishment (you mention HR) or a local "mom n' pop" type place. The laws may not be different for each, but operating procedures and action you can take may vary.

Frame challenge: will the employer allow you to buy additional shirts, preferably at wholesale prices? If you don't want to wash it every night, having several does reduce the frequency...

So, there are two separate questions:
Can your employer ask you to wear dirty clothes?
My thoughts on this is that usually it is the other way around - an employer can send someone home to change if they are not dressed appropriately (and appropriately is context specific - could mean insufficient PPE, could be a giant stain on a white shirt). However, I don't believe there is any law or rule for the inverse scenario.
Especially for a hospitality job, I would be mortified if my workers who were handling food came to work in stained, smelly clothes.
Some quick googling seemed to back up this thought. The only exception would be where the dirty uniform created a health and safety issue (and merely being dirty and smelly probably does not rise to that standard - although a good case could be made)
Can your employer refuse to provide additional shirts?
This is where it gets more interesting. It depends on your local laws - but generally - if a piece of clothing is specific to your job and has no additional benefit, then it is a uniform and it is the employer's responsibility to provide it.
For example, a white dress shirt, suit and tie could be considered a uniform of sorts (consider a law office), but because these can be used independently of work (formal events, church, weddings etc.) they aren't a uniform.
Whereas a T-shirt that has the company logo emblazoned on it can't be used for other purposes - it is a uniform and is to be supplied by the company.
There are some circumstances where the employer can insist that an employee pay for a uniform - if the employee ruined a uniform outside the course of their expected duties:

If you were cleaning the kitchen and spilt bleach on your T-shirt, that is part of your normal duties - not your fault.
If you were cleaning your home after work and still in your work T-shirt and spilt bleach, that is not part of your work duties = your fault.

There is also in most places bits around reasonable care and maintenance.
I know in some areas as well there is a concept around what is reasonable to provide. For example, for someone who works 4 days, it would not be reasonable to provide 8 shirts. A business could argue that providing 2 shirts is reasonable.
Really though - this part of the question really does depend on your local laws and as such, we can't really answer further.

Frame challenge. For me the key issue seems to be your statement

"...I haven't had a chance to wash it due to my late work hours and the laundromat's schedule.."

Unless you work on an oil rig, you simply need to find the time to keep your own work uniform clean. You can't rely on someone else doing it for you  and part of doing your job properly is ensuring that you're appropriately dressed for the occasion, even if that means making some slight effort.
I worked part-time in retail and at one point I only had one branded shirt. I used to hand-wash it each evening when I got home, and machine-wash it at least once a week on my day off.
Off the top of my head I can think of several options open to you.

Hand-wash your clothes and hang them on a radiator to dry. A cheap bottle of handwash liquid will set you back about a buck and is enough to last you a week.

Find a 24/7 laundromat. Check your local listings.

Buy a cheap portable washing machine. A desktop model will set you back less than $30 and can sit in your apartment next to your sink.



If you keep turning up to work in a dirty uniform they won't take that as hint to buy you extra uniforms, they'll just fire you.

While I think the true topic here are the laws, not washing utensils, you made a fair point. Before also losing the job, maybe try to handle the situation somehow until a solution is found.

@New2wheels-Pray4Me Still on you to keep your clothes clean and show up for work presentable.

@Stian - Based on OPs comments, they won't have this problem for much longer.

Hard to be definitive without a location to go by, however for me the key thing is this:

other employees are allowed to wear a variety of clothing, including cut-off t-shirts, basketball shorts, Crocs, and house slippers.

It would seem to be discriminatory to force an employee to wear a particular uniform when other employees doing similar work are not required to.
However, note the word force.  There would have to be some threat on the employers side, like a threat to send you home, deduct from wages, etc., to constitute a threat.  Otherwise they're just asking.

My employer says I have to buy additional shirts from a specific website

This may simply reflect the fact that these items have brand specific logos.  However it is not clear from your post if, e.g. your employer and the website you have to order from are linked.

For the past three days, I've worn this shirt, which has accumulated pizza sauce, pepper juice, flour, dough, BBQ sauce, Alfredo sauce, sardine juice, butter, and sweat. It's become unsanitary and disgusting, and I feel sick wearing it.

Personally I'd just look for another job at this point.  It doesn't sound like a nice job (from your point of view), and the company or immediate boss may be a problem.  You could start disputing this issue with your boss/employers, but really that's not going to achieve much except an even more unpleasant work-place.
So my advice is to move on.

There is very limittedinformation provided in the question. What bussiness are you working in? What country are you living in? All that matters.
From the contamination I suppose you work in the kitchen or at least food processing industry.
If you are forced to work in contaminated dress, instead of being sent home to get cleaned (with no pay for the day) it is a matter for hygiene.
Call hygiene office, get new job and avoid your current employer even as a customer.

You might consider dealing with this laundry concern by way of a  washboard if you don't want to buy additional uniform shirts.  You can use a washboard in your bathtub or a kitchen sink.  Add a very small amount of your normal detergent, wet the shirt, and agitate up and down on the washboard.  Rinse in cold water, wring out, and hang.  If you hang in a warm spot, chances are high that the shirt will be dry before your next shift.
It's not convenient, but it will do the job.  Please, let's completely dispel the idea that the employer is forcing you to show up in a dirty shirt.
POSTSCRIPT
For all you naysayers, I don't consider adding a photo of a washboard here as excessive at all.  For you people complaining, just think of the fact that there are millennials whose attention span has unfortunately been ruined by social media apps on their mobile devices.  Rather than linking elsewhere for said millennials to then get distracted again by whatever clickbait happens to show up, it is my intention to convey what this antiquated "washboard" thing is and how to use it, so they don't get lost.  If you've had the privilege of maybe a college education and never having to soil your hands at a fast food joint, well then a hip-hop-hooray to you, and I could see how it could insult you.  THIS response is for the kids at McDonald's who are working the register and who can't count change manually if the bill comes up to $9.01 and someone hands them $20.01.  They are legion, and have to be spoon fed.  These same people will be wiping your behinds in nursing homes one day, and if it goes sour, remember me!


Sorry, we are at Workplace here, not on LifeHacks or Household tips. Please consider retracting this "answer" pushing the questioneer into the state of "has to deal with it". There are laws. That is the topic here. Not washing utensils. This is not witty. It is insulting.

At least remove that image. You can provide a link maybe. Your text seems to be sincere at least.

@Antares Call it what you like.  I'm former enlisted -- Army Food Service.  There was never any excuse to show up to a garrison or field kitchen in dirty clothes, or even boots without a brush shine at minimum (high polish was not required).  High chance that OP's job is a minimum wage job, and such jobs are there to induce a bit of personal accountability, problem solving, and thinking outside of the box.   I've just provided an approach that's outside of the box.

Flagged answer for rudeness. -- It is not necessarily what you are proposing. It is the how with a billboard sized wash board implying the medieval ages approach or "rub it and all sorrows are gone". It is not even remotely aimed at the question either. Even though I do endorse helping outside the box. Not in a derogative manner tho.

such jobs are there to induce a bit of personal accountability, problem solving, and thinking outside of the box are they, though? This phrasing makes it seem like employers are offering the lowest legally-allowed pay out of the goodness of their hearts to promote character growth.

@Antares I am not exactly sure that the business is at fault in this case, given that many important bits are missing from the answer like what kind of business it is and where it is located. Based on likelier sets of circumstances, it might even be fairer for the OP to be the one to handle this thing all by themselves. Also, I really don't see the rudeness here, with all due respect. The image in the end looks redundant and reminds me of quora (), but the content itself is fine. I will edit it out for them, but I don't think the answer needs retracting.

Shakes fist at clouds and yells into the void about youngsters not knowing how good they have it.
